# Exclamation Point and Too Many Arguments

Tags: bash

I tried to setup a conditional in a bash script but I've run into an unusual error; bash is complaining of too many arguments, but everything seems correct to me:

```
[ "${foo:0:1}" = '!' -o "$foo" = '*' ]
```

Quite simply, the test should succeed if `$foo` is either an asterisk, or begins with an exclamation point.

However, when `$foo` begins with an exclamation point, I get the following error in bash:

```
bash: [: too many arguments
```

The weird thing is that it works fine if I omit the second condition like so:

```
[ "${foo:0:1}" = '!' ]
```

So it seems like the `"${foo:0:1}"` evaluating to an exclamation point is somehow interfering with the logical or condition, can anyone explain what's going on here, and what the best way would be to work around it?

It doesn't seem to matter what I'm testing for, for example:

```
[ "${foo:0:1}" = 'z' -o "$foo" = '*' ]
```

Will still fail if `$foo` begins with an exclamation point. This has me concerned, as I have numerous scripts that test characters in the same way that could presumably fail unexpectedly if a value contains an exclamation mark, so I could do with finding a good workaround for this.

Comment: I'm guessing you are running the script with `sh` instead of `bash`, which means you cannot use Bash extensions like `-o`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you aim for POSIX compatibility, prefer [`[[`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) over `[` when using bash. It is safer, easier and more powerful.

For example, you could use [regular expressions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF):

```
[[ $foo =~ '^(!|\*$)' ]]
```

And the `[[` construct supports `||` and `&&`, which you should prefer over the `-o` and `-a`:

```
[[ "${foo:0:1}" = '!' || "$foo" = '*' ]]
```

History expansion happens before variable expansion, so `foo` containing `!` shouldn't cause problems due to history expansion. What could be happening is that `[` sees `!` as a negation operator:

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
     This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last
    argument must be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
[[ ... ]]: [[ expression ]]
     Returns a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional
    expression EXPRESSION.  Expressions are composed of the same primaries used
    by the `test' builtin, and may be combined using the following operators

        ( EXPRESSION )  Returns the value of EXPRESSION
        ! EXPRESSION    True if EXPRESSION is false; else false
```

The full command (say, if `foo='!abcd'`) becomes:

```
[ '!' = '!' -o '!abcd' = '*' ]
```

Which would be parsed:

```
NOT(= '!' -o '!abcd' = '*')
```

And if you try the internal expression, you would get the same error:

```
$ [ = '!' -o a = a ]
sh: [: too many arguments
```

A common workaround is to prefix the strings with another character:

```
[ "z${foo:0:1}" = 'z!' -o "$foo" = '*' ]
```

Have a look [the Bash Hackers' Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#number_of_arguments_rules).

Comment: Thanks muru and @joao for both your answers! I'm going to pick this one  as it contains options for both bashisms and posix compliance, and I'll be opting for the bash specific solution(s) in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can workaround it by splitting your expression:

```
[ "${foo:0:1}" = '!' ] || [ "$foo" = '*' ]
```

So Bash doesn't misinterpret what you mean with `'!'` - if a string or a `not` operator.

Comment: This looks like an easy change for the numerous script of OP.

Comment: Yes, but please leave `=` as such. `==` instead of `=` in `[` is not standard and provides no benefit.

Comment: @jilles you are right, `=` is better with single `[`. Changed.